# How to sort file rows with vi?

Tags: sorting, vim, vi, multiple-columns

I have to edit multiple files with multiple rows, and also everything is in three columns, like this:

```
#file

save    get    go
go      save   get
rest    place  reset
```

Columns are separated with tab. Is there any possible way to sort rows based on **second** or **third** column using vi?

Comment: what do you mean second **or** third column ?

Comment: Do you need to use vi?  This could be much easier to do with sed/sort/cut *nix commands.

Comment: @Kent Look at my file, there are three columns there, I went to be able to sort rows alphabetically, according to contents of second col, or third col

Comment: @MichaelGardner This is not necessary to use vi, but using eternal commands will put me in trouble, I have to edit some huge files, **Multiple times**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sort by the 2nd col:

```
:sor /\t/
```

sort by the 3rd col:

```
:sor /\t[^\t]*\t/
```

Answer (score 1):

Second column:

```
:sort /\%9c/
```

Third column:

```
:sort /\%16c/
```

`\%16c` means "column 16".

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi light the rows you want to sort with "V" command
2. Use a bash command with "!" to work on the selection, like:

   !sort -k 10

Where the number is the column number where your second (sort) column starts.

vi will replace the selection with the output of the sort command - which is given the original selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a pattern for `sort`. For example:

```
sort /^\w*\s*/
```

Will sort on the second column (the first thing to sort after matching the pattern).

Likewise

```
sort /^\w*\s*\w*\s*/
```

Should sort on the third column.

Answer (score 0):

delimit the column using some char here I have | symbol as delimiter, once did with that you can use below command to sort specific column use -n if u want to sort numeric and its working on some version of vi and not on ubuntu vi :(

/|.*|/ | sort

Comment: // used to match a patern |.*| used to match words delimited between || and | as piping commend and sort to sort

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand. Can you [edit] to clarify and use sentences, please?  You can roll your comment into the answer since it seems like it was intended as an edit. Thanks.